# Get CPU and ram utilization of local and server in c# / ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, local, cpu-usage

Get CPU and ram utilization of local and server in c# / ASP.NET MVC

```cs
ramCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available MBytes", true);
var ram_Timer_Tick = Convert.ToInt32(ramCounter.NextValue()).ToString() + "Mb";
Thread.Sleep(1000);
return Json(ram_Timer_Tick, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Using this code I'm  getting ram utilization for local but for server I couldn't get it.

Comment: What does "local" mean here? And by "server" do you mean the ASP.NET application, the process hosting the ASP.NET application, or the machine as a whole?

Comment: yes ,server  mean the ASP.NET application.i want to get ram utilization of system on which my asp.net web application running

Comment: ...and "local"?

Comment: my local system

Comment: on server i am getting 404 (Not found )Error

Comment: 404 is a response code generated by the server. It means "page not found". It's unrelated to the code you've provided.